# Sequelize: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when try to create data on DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

i'm working on a personal project. Basically a node based blog to learn the language...

I already created the category and articles migration and models, now i'm trying to start the users creation.

Here's my Users **migration** (20201124222940-create_users.js):

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("users", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("users");
  },
};
```

This is my **Model** (User.js):

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'users'
        });
    }
}

module.exports = User;

//? Model de usuários
```

And, here's my **controller** (UsersController.js) that try to create a user.
I'm using bcrypt to create a hash and secure the password.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

router.get("/admin/users", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Listagem de usuários");
});

router.get("/admin/users/new", (req, res) => {
    res.render("admin/users/new");
});

router.post("/admin/users/create", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

    User.create({
        email: email,
        password: hash,
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect("/");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(email, password, hash, salt)
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

And the error that i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at User._initValues (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:140:49)
    at new Model (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:118:10)
    at new User (D:\dev\blog_node\models\User.js:3:1)
    at Function.build (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2157:12)
    at Function.create (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2207:23)
    at D:\dev\blog_node\controllers\UsersController.js:21:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)       
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\dev\blog_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I already test the constants hash, password, salt, email..
Already tried to create some manual data like: password: "123", email: "asda@asda.com".
Already compared to the other two models and controllers and nothing came up.

So, where i'm failling?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
@Anatoly noticed that don't called my User.init

So... before the comment:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dbConfig = require('./database');

const Category = require("../models/Category");
const Article = require("../models/Article");

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

Category.init(connection);
Article.init(connection);

Category.associate(connection.models);
Article.associate(connection.models);


module.exports = connection;
```

After his comment:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const dbConfig = require('./database');

const Category = require("../models/Category");
const Article = require("../models/Article");
const User = require("../models/User");

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

Category.init(connection);
Article.init(connection);
User.init(connection);

Category.associate(connection.models);
Article.associate(connection.models);


module.exports = connection;
```

AWESOMEEEE!!! <3
Solved the problem!

Comment: I don't see where you call `User.init`

Comment: @Anatoly u're awesome! I'll edit with the solution now!

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question. Double check that this is a valid, unique question that will help others in the future and can be found by searching for relevant terms (the title looks like that won't be the case); if it passes all that, feel free to roll back the edit and post an answer yourself, alternative delete the question to save the curators some time. (I also don't mean to be rude in any way; I'm just giving you a rundown of how SO works, because the people that run this site have decided to leave that to us and the only way we can is via comments)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `User` model before use it like this:

```
User.init(connection);
```

Add this initialization along with other models' initialization code.